# GNU parallel with dependencies?

Tags: bash, dependencies, gpu, gnu-parallel

Is there a way to run scripts with dependencies via GNU `parallel`?

I wish to run the following scripts:

```
aa_00.sh     # run time ~6 hr
aa_01.sh     # dependent on aa_00.sh; ~6 hr
aa_02.sh     # dependent on aa_00.sh; ~6 hr
aa_03.sh     # dependent on aa_00.sh; ~6 hr

bb_00.sh     # run time ~2 hr
bb_01.sh     # dependent on bb_00.sh; ~2 hr
bb_02.sh     # dependent on bb_00.sh; ~2 hr
bb_03.sh     # dependent on bb_00.sh; ~2 hr
```

Scripts `aa_01.sh`, `aa_02.sh`, and `aa_03.sh` must not run until script `aa_00.sh` completes.

Scripts `aa_01.sh`, `aa_02.sh`, and `aa_03.sh` are completely independent of each other and can run in parallel.

Similarly, scripts `bb_01.sh`, `bb_02.sh`, and `bb_03.sh` must not run until script `bb_00.sh` completes.

Scripts `bb_01.sh`, `bb_02.sh`, and `bb_03.sh` are completely independent of each other and can run in parallel.

I have 4 CPUs [*].

[*] Actually, I am using GPUs so I am using:

```
'eval CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES={%} {}'
# i removed the "({%} - 1)" notation just for simplicity here
```

Is there a way to run these 8 scripts efficiently such that the dependencies on `aa_00.sh` and `bb_00.sh` are respected?

One idea I had was at the completion of `aa_00.sh`, release the subsequent `aa_{1,2,3}.sh` scripts via `parallel`. And at the completion of `bb_00.sh`, release the subsequent `bb_{1,2,3}.sh` scripts via `parallel`. But because two different runs of `parallel` are used, the `bb_*` scripts don't know that `aa_*` scripts are running (and vice versa):

```
cat commands_aa.txt
  aa_01.sh
  aa_02.sh
  aa_03.sh
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 aa_00.sh
parallel -j4 -a commands_aa.txt 'eval CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES={%} {}'

cat commands_bb.txt
  bb_01.sh
  bb_02.sh
  bb_03.sh
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 bb_00.sh
parallel -j4 -a commands_bb.txt 'eval CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES={%} {}'
```

Conceptually, I'd like to add inputs to an already running `parallel` command. I tried overwriting the `-a commands.txt` file when `parallel` was already running but that did not achieve what I wanted (I would have been shocked if that *did* work).

In actuality, I have more than just `aa` and `bb` scripts; I have as many as 8 or 10 (ie, `aa`, `bb`, ..., `hh`, `ii`, ...).  And I have more than 3 scripts that run after the `_00` script; I have 12 in total: `_00` + `_01`, ..., `_11`. All of them have the dependency on their respective `_00` script.

I was looking at the python library `luigi`, too.  `luigi` can handle dependencies but I don't think it can handle parallelization. I also looked at the python module `joblib.Parallel()`. Perhaps I need to combine `luigi` and `joblib.Parallel()`.

Thank you.

**Additional Thoughts**

- I do think what I need is to have each `_00` script add its dependents upon its completion.
- But I need to add these dependents to the list that `parallel` is *already working on*.

Something like this (conceptually):

1. `commands.txt` contains:

```
aa_00.sh
bb_00.sh
```

2. run `parallel`:

```
parallel -j4 -a commands.txt 'eval CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES={%} {}'
```

3. `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1` <-- `aa_00.sh`
4. `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2` <-- `bb_00.sh`
5. when `bb_00.sh` completes it appends its dependencies to the bottom of `commands.txt`, like so:
6. `commands.txt` updated:

```
aa_00.sh  # still running on GPU 1
bb_00.sh  # this completed on GPU 2
bb_01.sh  # these new scripts are
bb_02.sh  #   appended to
bb_03.sh  #   commands.txt
```

7. Somehow, `parallel` magically is okay with these new lines of input and these new scripts are queued to GPUs 3, 4, and 2.
8. `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=3` <-- `bb_01.sh`
9. `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=4` <-- `bb_02.sh`
10. `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2` <-- `bb_03.sh`
11. `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1` <-- still running `aa_03.sh`
12. `bb_01.sh` completes on GPU 3; no dependencies so nothing is appended to `commands.txt`

The joblog would look something like:

```
aa_00.sh  GPU=1  running
bb_00.sh  GPU=2  completed
bb_01.sh  GPU=3  completed
bb_02.sh  GPU=4  running
bb_03.sh  GPU=2  running
```

14. Eventually `aa_00.sh` completes so it appends its dependencies to the bottom of `commands.txt`.
15. `commands.txt` updated:

```
aa_00.sh  # completed on GPU 1
bb_00.sh  # completed on GPU 2
bb_01.sh  # completed on GPU 3
bb_02.sh  # running on GPU 4
bb_03.sh  # running on GPU 2
aa_01.sh  # these new scripts are
aa_02.sh  #   appended to
aa_03.sh  #   commands.txt
```

16. Again, `parallel` is magically okay with these new lines of input so it dishes out the new scripts to available GPUs.
17. `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=3` <-- `aa_01.sh`
18. `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1` <-- `aa_02.sh`
19. Suppose `bb_02.sh` completes next, freeing up GPU 4.
20. `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=4` <-- `aa_03.sh`

Now the joblog looks something like:

```
aa_00.sh  GPU=1  completed
bb_00.sh  GPU=2  completed
bb_01.sh  GPU=3  completed
bb_02.sh  GPU=4  completed
bb_03.sh  GPU=2  completed
aa_01.sh  GPU=3  running
aa_02.sh  GPU=1  running
aa_03.sh  GPU=4  running
```

(I may have mixed up the numbering and surely the timing isn't correct (aa runs 3x longer than bb), but hopefully I explained the ordering correctly.)

It's the "magical" part of `parallel` that I'm unsure of.

Comment: Consider using Airflow or other tools, that handle exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example-gnu-parallel-as-queue-system-batch-manager

So something like:

```
true >jobqueue; tail -n+0 -f jobqueue | parallel -j4 'eval CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES={%} {}'
echo "aa_00.sh; (echo aa_01.sh; echo aa_02.sh; echo aa_03.sh) >> jobqueue" >> jobqueue
echo "bb_00.sh; (echo bb_01.sh; echo bb_02.sh; echo bb_03.sh) >> jobqueue" >> jobqueue
```

We are clearly in territory where there must be better tools: GNU Parallel does not have a dependency graph like `make` has.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great solution.
Looking at the solution at the link, the logic around stopping the process is less obvious, but `tail -n+0 -f jobqueue` is brilliant.